# Игнорирование изменения значения с помощью триггера ms sql

Tags: sql-server, триггер

Есть таблица

```
USE [TestDB]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TestTable]    Script Date: 03.09.2018 12:01:25 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
    [Id] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [GC] [nvarchar](max) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Как написать такой триггер, чтобы в запросе игнорировалось поле GC, если оно null?  Например, при запросе:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[TestTable]
   SET [Name] = 'New test'
      ,[Id] = 5
      ,[GC] = null
GO
```

Были обновлены поля Name и Id, а при запросе:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[TestTable]
   SET [Name] = 'New test'
      ,[Id] = 5
      ,[GC] = 'asdf'
GO
```

Изменились все три поля?

Comment: Может лучше использовать хранимые процедуры?

Comment: А каким образом мне могут помочь хранимые процедуры? Как может быть построен flow через них, если клиентское приложение я изменить не могу?

Comment: изменение id в запросе, это просто неудачный пример? или вы предполагаете менять потенциальный первичный ключ?

Comment: Да, пример неудачный, хотел передать суть, но... Конечно, первичный ключ не меняется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если в таблице есть первичный ключ (допустим в примере, что это поле [Id]), можно реализовать через `INSTEAD OF` триггер

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.tUpdateTestTable
ON [dbo].[TestTable]
INSTEAD OF UPDATE
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE t
SET [GC] = ISNULL(i.[GC], t.[GC]),
    [Name] = ISNULL(i.[Name], t.[Name])
FROM TestTable t
  JOIN inserted i ON i.[Id] = t.[Id];
END
```

Comment: хотел было подобное написать в ответ, но меня что-то смутило изменение id в запросе

Comment: Ответ работает. Есть несколько моментов, которые меня смущают. 1. Join. Делать допзапрос для каждого обновления? Он мне кажется лишним, может я и не прав. 2. Мне придется генерировать присвоения для всех полей, что не всегда тривиально для ORM.

Comment: Не понял вопросов. Если есть таблица с набором полей, которые точно идентифицируют запись, то на ней можно создать по образу и подобию триггер в котором таблица связывается по ключу с inserted и обновляются все поля, кроме ключа. Если ключа нет, то ничего не получится, потому что не по чему будет привязать таблицу inserted. Что такое "допзапрос для каждого обновления" и зачем его делать? Зачем генерировать присвоения для всех полей?

Answer (score 2):

Для этих целей вообще не обязательно использовать триггер, вы можете использовать функцию `coalesce` в update-запросе, которая вернет вам первое не null-значение ее аргумента. Так что передав туда новое значение поля и вторым параметров - старое значение, вы получите желаемое поведение

```
UPDATE TestTable SET  gc = COALESCE('new value', gc)
```

Если передадите `new value` то значение будет обновлено на него. Если передадите `null`, то значение `gc` не изменится.

*зы: `id`  переместите в начало таблицы*

Comment: Ответ хороший, но бывают и ситуации, когда нет возможности влиять на формирование запроса. Например, запрос может формироваться сторонним приложением.

Comment: К сожалению, запросы формируются ORM. С помощью GC определяется удален ли объект (т.е. это служебное поле). Можно ли сделать описанное вами поведение без изменения запросов?